# Updating SQLite - near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I recently added a column to my SQLite database, since adding this column a button which I had which sets the value of one of the database columns to "1" or "0" have now started to crash my application when the button tries to use the `updateData(),` so I assume thats where my issue is, is in the code or the syntax of the `updateData()`

Error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error
> (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE my_manager SET
> location_name = 'blarney stone' , location_county =
> 'Cork',location_description = 'jj',location_route =
> '1',location_position = '2',location_longg = 'null',location_lat =
> 'null',location_url = 'JJ',location_url2 = 'jj',location_url3 = 'jj',
> WHERE location_id = '1'
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> Method)

Code:

```
 void updateData(String id, String row_id, String name, String county, String description, String 
  in_route, String position, String lat, String longg, String url, String url2, String url3) {
    System.out.println(TABLE_NAME+"; "+row_id +"; "+ name +"; "+ county+"; "+ description+"; " + lat 
   +"; "+ longg+"; "+ url +"; "+ url2 +"; "+ url3 +"; ");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + "my_manager" + " SET location_name = "+"'"+ name + "' " + ", " +
            "location_county = " + "'"+ county + "'"+ "," +
            "location_description = " + "'"+ description +  "'" + "," +
            "location_route = " + "'"+ in_route +  "'" + "," +
            "location_position = " + "'"+ position +  "'" + "," +
            "location_longg = " + "'"+ longg +  "'" + "," +
            "location_lat = " + "'"+ lat +  "'" + "," +
            "location_url = " + "'"+ url +  "'" + "," +
            "location_url2 = " + "'"+ url2 +  "'" + "," +
            "location_url3 = " + "'"+ url3 +  "'" + "," + " WHERE location_id = "+"'"+ row_id+"'");
```

Comment: Remove the `,` before WHERE.

Comment: As @forpas said, it should be: `"location_url3 = " + "'"+ url3 +  "' WHERE`

Comment: Don't use string pasting; use parameterized statements.

Comment: remove the "," worked, cheers gents

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my friend don't take this as a bad but how about you avoid to much unnecessary "+" if it is possible.

```
void updateData("UPDATE my_manager SET location_name = '"+ name + "', " +
            "location_county = '"+ county + "', " +
            "location_description = '"+ description +  "'," +
            "location_route = '"+ in_route +  "', " +
            "location_position = '" + position + "', " +
            "location_longg = '" + longg + "'," +
            "location_lat = '" + lat +  "'," +
            "location_url = '" + url +  "', " +
            "location_url2 = '"+ url2 +  "', " +
            "location_url3 = '"+ url3 +  "' WHERE location_id = '"+ row_id+"'");
```